# How to add Vue to existing Webpack project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have a Webpack project, and I want to use Vue in it. I'm importing Vue in my JavaScript file like this:

```
import "../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js";
```

I can see `vue.min.js` in my bundle, but when I try to instantiate Vue in my HTML file or JavaScript file like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: ‘#app’,
  data: {
    message: ‘Hello Vue!’
  }
})
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
    at eval (ins.js?be14:2)
    at Object../src/scripts/ins.js (app.js:485)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:79)
    at eval (index.js?48f5:1)
    at Module../src/scripts/index.js (app.js:474)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:79)
    at Object.0 (app.js:530)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:79)
    at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
    at app.js:152
```

I tried to add `vue.min.js` directly in my HTML via CDN, and everything works fine. Is there is some ordering problem on load? How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import Vue to a variable like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'; // or import Vue from '../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js';
```

It should then work with your example:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var app = new Vue({
  el: ‘#app’,
  data: {
    message: ‘Hello Vue!’
  }
})
```

Comment: @user3348410 No problem ;)